# operation in list, got some problem in indexing

Tags: python, indexing, list-comprehension

[image]

I was taking a test and I stuck in this problem. I don't understand why [output] is showing [10,23,56,[95]] instead of [10,34,56,[95]]

Comment: Looks like wrong answer in test.

Comment: @Shiv The answer is correct if you try running the code on you own.

Comment: @Tzane What I mean is that `[10, 23, 56. [95]]` is wrong answer as `a[1] = 34` is the assignment.

Comment: @Shiv the answer in the test is correct

Comment: when you use `b=list(a)` you create a copy of `a`, but you also copy the reference of the list in the list. so when you change a single number in `a` you dont change it in `b`, but if you change the list object in the list, you change it in both, because you copied the reference to the list

Comment:  http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html

Answer (score 3):

this is to do with the fact that a[3] is just a pointer to the list [78].

for this example lets say the location of a[3] is 0xlocation

meaning that b = [10, 23, 56, 0xlocation] where 0xlocation is still a[3].
so every changes you do to a[3] will be done to b[3] and same the other way around

the rest of the numbers are not pointers because they are not lists.
as stated in line 2 b is a new list created from a.
thats why when they did a[1] = 34 it did not apply to b[1]

if line 2 was just b = a then b will just be a pointer to a. and in that case every changes done to a will be done to b and same the other way around

Comment: Thanks Man. I get your point here.. May Allah S.W.T help you and guide you.. JazakAllah

Answer (score 2):

On line 2 list `b` is created from values of list `a`, one of which is another list that is pointing to the same object in both lists `a` and `b`. So if you modify the value in list `a`, it is also changed in list `b`.

If you check the identities with `id`, you can see they are the same:

```
a = [10, 23, 56, [78]]
b = list(a)
a[3][0] = 95
a[1] = 34
print(b)

print(id(a[3]))
print(id(b[3]))
```

Comment: Yeah! You are right but I am not talking about 95  I am talking about why 23 is not changed to 34 when I print b..

Comment: @DanishAnalyst `23` is an `int` which is not mutable, meaning you can't change its value without changing the object itself, so there is no reference between lists `a` and `b` for `23`. You can check this about mutable and immutable types: https://www.mygreatlearning.com/blog/understanding-mutable-and-immutable-in-python/

Comment: I know what you are talking about, I am well aware with the concept of mutability and immutability.. You are not getting my point here... let me help u to understand:                if you take input as a list like `a = [10,12,23,24]` but when I apply indexing like 'a[2] = 34' then I print my list `a` it will give the output like this `[10,12,34,24]` here as you can see  `23` is replaced by `34` but not in the case of my Question... I am asking why it is happening in my question when I assign in my code line `4`... `23` is not replaced by `34`.

Comment: Im not sure if I understand you here. On line 4, the assignment is is done to list `a`, not `b` so why do you think the value in `b` should change as well?